# Integral of $\sqrt{\tan x}$ using $u$-sub then complex partial fraction decomposition

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I wanted to try and solve this famously deceiving integral without completing the square or phase shifting as normally shown in videos and purely using complex factorization and going from there.

I got it (almost), but my answer differed by a negative sign in the final answer and wanted to know where I went wrong in my work

Here's my work in LaTeX:

$ I =\displaystyle\int{\sqrt{\tan{x}}} \, dx $

let $u = \sqrt{\tan{x}} \, , du = \displaystyle\frac{u^4 + 1 }{2u} \, dx $

$I = \displaystyle \int{\frac{2u^2}{u^4 - (-1) } \, du} $

$I = \displaystyle \int{\frac{2u^2}{u^4 - (i^2) } \, du} $

$I = \displaystyle 2\int{\frac{u^2}{(u^2 + i )(u^2 - i)} \, du} $

$I = \displaystyle 2\int{\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{u^2+i } \, du} + \displaystyle 2\int{\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{u^2 - i}} \, du$

$I = \displaystyle \int{\frac{1}{u^2 + i} du} + \displaystyle\int{\frac{1}{u^2 - i } \, du} $

$I = \displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}\arctan{\left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{i}}\right)} + \displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}\operatorname{arctanh}{\left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{i}}\right)}$

My Answer: $I = \displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}\arctan{\left(\frac{\sqrt{\tan{x}}}{\sqrt{i}}\right)} + \displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}\operatorname{arctanh}{\left(\frac{\sqrt{\tan{x}}}{\sqrt{i}}\right)}$

Real Answer:
$I = \displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}\arctan{\left(\frac{\sqrt{\tan{x}}}{\sqrt{i}}\right)} - \displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}\operatorname{arctanh}{\left(\frac{\sqrt{\tan{x}}}{\sqrt{i}}\right)}$

Thank you for your help - Alex

Comment: Your mistake is in the integral $\displaystyle\int{\frac{1}{u^2 - i } \, du}$

Answer (score 2):

You presumably just misremembered an antiderivative. We have that
$$
\int \frac{1}{1-x^2} \, \mathrm{d} x = \operatorname{artanh}(x) + C
$$
and therefore, by multiplying the denominator by $-1$,
$$
\int \frac{1}{x^2-1} \, \mathrm{d} x = -\operatorname{artanh}(x) + C
$$
(i.e. you forgot the negative here).